# Flexbox grid - best way to affix child item to absolute position left and upwards?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to visualize queue's and processes in a system. Each process has one (for now) corresponding queue that it fetches data from. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

But i am struggling to make this work in a "non-hacky" way. The main problem is getting the be where i want them to be - skewed to the left and upwards. Right now, each process and queue are placed in a Col. That col is then split into two smaller Cols - one for the process and one for the queue.  (pseudo-code)

```
<Row>
   <Col>
    <Col md=3 queue />
      <Queue style={position relative top -XX%, left - YY%} />
    <Col md=9 process />
  </Col>
</Row>
```

This works if i tune the offset based on the number of processes i am currently displaying but i don't want to do that. I want to solve this "the flexbox-way" but i am not sure how i would go about that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a starting point for a flexbox-approach:

```css
.processes {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.process {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative
}

.queue {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px
}
```

```html
<div class="processes">
  <div class="process">
    Process 1
    <div class="queue">
      Queue
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="process">
    Process 2
    <div class="queue">
      Queue
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="process">
    Process 3
    <div class="queue">
      Queue
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think css grid is a better solution.
Here's an example of what you can achieve.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}


.process, .quee {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.process {
  justify-self: end;
}

.quee {
  justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <article class="quee">quee</article>
    <article class="quee">quee</article>
    <article class="quee">quee</article>
    <article class="process">process</article>
    <article class="process">process</article>
    <article class="process">process</article>

</div>
```